# Skip blank columns in csv.DictReader

Tags: python

A sample of my input looks like this , Too give a brief understanding. This is a matrix of User ratings where the  columns are product numbers.

```
User    95  94  97  101 99  87  98  86  103 105 106 100 92  89  91  96
27669   15  19      2   1                                           
27670               12  9   61  51  69  30  32  30  10              
27671                                                   49  7   29  
27672   11  73                      43  47  12                      6
27673           8       14      11                  11              
27674                   1   55                                      
27675                       9           9       10      30  29  11  
27676                               29  50  50                      
27677           31      25          28                              
27678           9   9       27  7   49              7               
27679       28                      27                              7
27680   52  47              40      55      52                      
27681                               11                  9       15  
27682   28  50              27                                      49
27683           9   9   10      8   12              9   10  8
```

I am using the code below to read the csv and convert it to a Dictionary

```
import csv
reader= csv.DictReader(open('test_23.csv'))
next(reader)
users = {}
for row in reader:
    key=row.pop('User')
    if key in users:
        pass
    users[key]=row
print users
```

A sample out put of my code is as below

```
{'31550': {'91': '', '88': '', '89': '', '97': '', '103': '', '100': '', '86': '', '87': '', '101': '', '95': '', '105': '', '99': '', '98': '', '102': '69', '90': '', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '', '94': '', '104': '', '96': ''}, '29443': {'91': '90', '88': '', '89': '69', '97': '', '103': '65', '100': '', '86': '', '87': '74', '101': '', '95': '', '105': '68', '99': '', '98': '', '102': '', '90': '', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '70', '94': '', '104': '74', '96': ''}, '32103': {'91': '', '88': '', '89': '', '97': '', '103': '', '100': '3', '86': '', '87': '', '101': '28', '95': '', '105': '65', '99': '', '98': '4', '102': '', '90': '', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '69', '94': '', '104': '68', '96': ''}, '29687': {'91': '', '88': '9', '89': '7', '97': '', '103': '8', '100': '', '86': '', '87': '', '101': '', '95': '', '105': '', '99': '', '98': '', '102': '9', '90': '25', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '27', '94': '', '104': '9', '96': ''}, '29444': {'91': '69', '88': '60', '89': '71', '97': '', '103': '', '100': '', '86': '51', '87': '', '101': '', '95': '19', '105': '', '99': '', '98': '', '102': '', '90': '', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '', '94': '35', '104': '', '96': '18'}, '28224': {'91': '', '88': '18', '89': '18', '97': '', '103': '', '100': '', '86': '', '87': '17', '101': '', '95': '17', '105': '', '99': '', '98': '', '102': '', '90': '17', '93': '', '92': '19', '106': '', '94': '19', '104': '', '96': '17'}, '31783': {'91': '', '88': '', '89': '', '97': '', '103': '50', '100': '', '86': '', '87': '', '101': '47', '95': '55', '105': '', '99': '', '98': '54', '102': '', '90': '', '93': '', '92': '', '106': '', '94': '', '104': '53', '96': ''},
```

Is there a way so that Dictreader can skip the blank values ?

Also ,Is there a way to remove the single quotes for all values ?

I have tried quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE but that doesnt work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `defaultdict` and do it all in one step.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict

users = defaultdict(dict)

for row in DictReader(open('./file.csv', 'rb')):
    key = row.pop('User')
    tmp_dict = {int(k):int(v) for k,v in row.iteritems() if v != ''}
    users[key] = tmp_dict

>>> users
{'27671':{89:7, 91:29, 92:49}, ... }
```

Comment: thanks , this seems elegant . but not why I get this  in my output


defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {{'27671':{89:7, 91:29, 92:49}, ... }

Comment: you can type `dict(users)` if you dont like the way the output looks, but it is the same thing ... just a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes are a python thing so you would have to first convert to a string and then remove them yourself:

```
str s = str(users).replace("'","")
```

I don't know a default way to tell the CSV reader not to read blanks but you could just loop over the dictionary and remove all values that are blank:

```
users = {k: v for k,v in users.iteritems() if v != ""}
```

Comment: str s = str(users).replace("'","")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I get the aboe error . I am using python 2.7

Comment: sorry drop the first `str`

Comment: tried both . both quotes and blank values still remain =)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
reader= csv.DictReader(open('test_23.csv'))
users = {}
newlist = {}

for row in reader:

    key =row.pop('User')
    if key in users:
        pass      


    for val in row:
        if row[val] != '':
            newlist[val] = int(row[val])
        else:
            pass

    users[key]=newlist
```